# Symfony 2.4 : Knp paginator Bundle Installation issue

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, knppaginator

I got this error while I configured [Knp paginator Bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) with Symfony 2.4

**ERROR :
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "KnpPaginatorBundle" from namespace "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle" in D:\Projects\wamp\www\Stutorial\app\AppKernel.php line 29. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?**

I followed this steps to install [Knp paginator Bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle).

```
# Install Knp components
git clone git://github.com/KnpLabs/knp-components.git vendor/knp-components

# Install knp paginator bundle
git clone git://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle.git vendor/bundles/Knp/Bundle/PaginatorBundle
```

My config.yml file:

```
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template
```

I added two lines in my autoload_namespaces.php

```
'Knp\\Component'      => array($vendorDir.'/knp-components/src'),
'Knp\\Bundle'         => array($vendorDir.'/bundles'),
```

And this line to AppKernel.php file

```
new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your plugin folder to `vendor/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/`, so now the real path would be: `vendor/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/Knp/Bundle/PaginatorBundle/`.